# Xcode interface builder resets NSToolbarItem sizes on its own, then complains about it

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nsbutton, nstoolbaritem

Ever since updating to Xcode 8 and Sierra, I get the following error message in the console when running the app:

> NSToolbarItem (NSToolbarItem: 0x608000121360) had to adjust the size of NSButton: 0x608000140160 from {35, 25} to the expected size of {37, 27}. Make sure that this toolbar item view has a valid frame/min/max size. This is an app bug, please do not file a bug against AppKit or NSToolbar! Break on _NSToolbarAdjustedBorderedControlSizeBreakpoint

What I have for this item is a `NSToolbarItem` containing a `NSButton`. The button's width is set to 35, and the height field is greyed out and disabled. The enclosing toolbar item has a Minimum size of 35 x 25 and Maximum size of 39 x 27 (I would like them to have the same value for min and max but keep reading). I tried setting the toolbar item's min a max to the same either 35 x 25, 37 x 27 and 39 x 27 but **on every occasion**, after saving the file and switching to a new file, for sure IB has changed those values on its own to something slightly different (increases the max width and height by 2 I think), and the storyboard file appears darker in the sidebar, indicating an unsaved change. Only when I run the project just after saving do the values stay as indicated (and the console warning goes away).

I'm getting really annoyed to have to change those values back before each build.. why is IB not keeping my values and then complaining about it?